# Why is UITableCell not displaying content

Tags: objective-c, ios

I made a custom cell in a UITableView using IB and Storyboards.  The code below is the code to load that custom cell;  the problem is although there is valid data in cA.cBusName and cA.cOrderDate, the cell labels (cell.busNameLabel.text, cell.orderDateLagbel.text) do not get set.  **Question is: Why is this not working?**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomerListingsCell";

    CustomerListingsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomerListingsCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    SingletonListOfCustomers *shareInstance = [SingletonListOfCustomers sharedInstance];
    cArray *cA = [shareInstance.listOfCustomers objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    cell.busNameLabel.text = cA.cBusName;
    cell.orderDateLabel.text = cA.cOrderDate;

    NSLog(@"\n\nindexPath.row: %d, busNameLabel: %@, orderDateLabel: %@", indexPath.row, cA.cBusName, cA.cOrderDate);
    NSLog(@"\nindexPath.row: %d, cell.busNameLabel: %@, cell.orderDateLabel: %@", indexPath.row, cell.busNameLabel.text, cell.orderDateLabel.text);

    return cell;

}
```

CustomerListingsCell is defined as:

```
@interface CustomerListingsCell : UITableViewCell  {

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *busNameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *orderDateLabel;

@end
```

The NSLog statement output is:

> 2012-05-24 14:01:55.363 Blank Fabrics[4876:f803]
>
> indexPath.row: 0, busNameLabel: Hidden Stitches, orderDateLabel:
>   05/24/2012 2012-05-24 14:01:55.364 Blank Fabrics[4876:f803] 
>   indexPath.row: 0, cell.busNameLabel: (null), cell.orderDateLabel:
>   (null) 2012-05-24 14:01:55.365 Blank Fabrics[4876:f803]
>
> indexPath.row: 1, busNameLabel: Prager, Software, orderDateLabel:
>   05/24/2012 2012-05-24 14:01:55.373 Blank Fabrics[4876:f803] 
>   indexPath.row: 1, cell.busNameLabel: (null), cell.orderDateLabel:
>   (null)

Comment: Can you show an example of what the 2 NSLog statements print?  (And maybe just `NSLog(@"Cell: %@", cell);` too?)

Comment: UPDATED with NSLog statements as requested...

Comment: Try using cell.textLabel.text = cA.cBusName; If it works then the connections on your custom tableviewcell are wrong.

Comment: Now I'm really curious to see the result of `NSLog(@"Cell: %@, Label: %@", cell, cell.busNameLabel);`.

Comment: Phillip:  this is the result:
2012-05-24 14:12:36.660 Blank Fabrics[4941:f803] Cell: <CustomerListingsCell: 0x6aa14e0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x6aa1650>>, Label: (null)
2012-05-24 14:12:36.662 Blank Fabrics[4941:f803] Cell: <CustomerListingsCell: 0x6aa43f0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x6aa30f0>>, Label: (null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your IBOutlets set for both the labels? Check if cell.busNameLabel is not nil...

Comment: iTukker... yes they are nil (checked after the allocation)... how could that be?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: you are not loading the nib-file when creating the cell.

Comment: Using storyboards, I don't have access to the NIB.  Anyway, I found the problem, thanks iTukker.  The problem was I was using the wrong "identifier" for the cell; I was using "CustomerListingsCell" when it should have been "Customers".  Thank you everybody for taking the time to help me.  I really appreciate it!